# Show Only NaT rows in python

Tags: python, pandas

Can anyone help me?

I want to check how many transactions are not paid.

Which is I need to show the table that 'paid_at' columns is NaT right?(CMIIW)

How to solve it?

[Here is the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgt51.png)

Comment: Have you tried df.value_counts()? https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html

Comment: @abaporu should i count the paid at columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
not_paid = df[df['paid_at'].isna()]
```